# Quick Vectors with Motion Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following prompt:

"The position of a car moving along a flat surface at time $t$ is modeled by $(x(t), y(t))$ with velocity vector $v(t)=<3+6\sin(3t), 1+e^{2t}>$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2$. Both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are measured in feet, and $t$ is measured in seconds. At time $t=0$, the car is at position $(0,0)$. Write, but do not evaluate, an integral expression that gives the total distance traveled by the car from time $t=0$ to time $t=2$."

I guess I'm a bit confused about what that integral might look like. I understand that the bounds of the integral would be from $0$ to $2$, but I'm a bit confused about what expression the question is looking for to be integrated. Any clarification would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen how to find arc length with parametrized curves before?

Comment: I don't think I've seen that before.

Comment: I see -- unfortunately I think that's what this question is asking for. In what context did you get this question?

Comment: This came up when I was studying for a test, any idea of how I might be able to finish it?

Comment: Well my idea would be to use the formula for arc length of a parametric, such as https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArcLength.aspx. But if that concept is not on the syllabus for the test, I'm not sure how else to do it.

Comment: Oh ok, just read through this and this makes sense. I guess now I'm confused about what my $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ would be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\mathbf{v}(t) = \langle \frac{dx}{dt}(t), \frac{dy}{dt}(t)\rangle$ and you were given $\mathbf{v}(t)$, you should have enough to plug into the arc length formula now.